# Error message: It seems an old version of PyDev Debugger is being used (please update the pydev package being used)

Tags: debugging

This message pops up here and there:
[image]

It looks pretty odd and text is the same as main title of this page: "It seems an old version of PyDev Debugger is being used (please update the pydev package being used)".

I have tried to update pydev (current version is 12.0.0.202402010911), but I am at the latest version, so I don't know how to fix this issue!
[image]

The version of Eclipse that I am running is from March of 2024 (Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
Build id: 20240307-1437):
[image]